# Java Array using User Input and Doubles

Tags: java, arrays, double, user-input

Our prompt for the problem is as follows:

> This function will fill an array of doubles.
>   It takes as its argument an array of doubles: the array that will hold the numeric information. It
>   returns an integer that is equal to the number of values that were placed in the array.
>   The function should start by declaring any variables that are needed. At a minimum, there should
>   be two variables: an integer that will be used as a subscript and a double that will be used to hold
>   a value that is entered by the user.
>   Initialize the subscript variable to the beginning of the array.
>   Prompt the user for a double number. This value should be saved in the double variable that was
>   declared earlier.
>   Inside of a loop that will execute as long as the the double number is not -99.99, the double
>   number should be put into the array at the subscript position, the subscript should be incremented
>   by 1, and the user should should be prompted for another double number.
>   Once the loop is finished executing, the number of values that were placed in the array should be
>   returned.

So far I have tried:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Current list is " + list);

            System.out.println("Enter : ");
            list.add(input.next());

            if (input = -99.99)

        } while (x == 0);

        input.close();
        System.out.println("List is " + list);
        String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

But am not able to compare the input to -99.99.

I would really appreciate if you guys took a look at my problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing scanner ith -99.99

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
        System.out.println("Enter : ");
        String next = input.next();
        list.add(next);

        if (Integer.parseInt(next) == -99.99) {
           // do logic
        }

    } while (x == 0);

    input.close();
    System.out.println("List is " + list);
    String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am so how would I be able to compare those two in a different way?

Comment: @john288992 Compare  what?

Comment: Holy cow, I didn't realize you fixed my problem in your previous submission. Thank you so much!